# must create a rule that captures the first preg_replace bar url

Tags: php

must create a rule that captures the first preg_replace bar url:

`http://localhost/item/other`

must take the rule just 'item' regardless of what comes after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the php [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function

An example would be:

```
$parts = parse_url("http://localhost/item/other");
$path_parts= explode('/', $parts[path]);
$item = $path_parts[1];
echo $item;
```

Answer (score -1):

It does not look like you have a specific question. I am assuming you are about write some routes script.

```
    $request_uri = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $delimiter = array_shift($request_uri);
    $controller = array_shift($request_uri);
    $action = array_shift($request_uri);
    if(preg_match('/item/i', $controller))
    {
        // do something right
    }
    else 
    {
        // do something wrong
    }
```

Comment: correct, is the routes script
but I can not set the action at this stage
just need to recover / item / with nothing before or after

There is another hint?
thanks

Comment: You like to make things difficult don't you ?  3 X array_shift ??? Try to help users with build in functions like parse_url(), that's why they exist.

Comment: Did you know the different? By using `array_shift` it will avoid us to write a validation procedure, since `array_shift` returns the shifted value, or NULL if array is empty or is not an array. Of course this does not need to apply if you assume each input/url does not need to validate, which will lead to "harmless" application. Also, `parse_url()` doesn't work with relative URLs and intended specifically for the purpose of parsing URLs and not URIs (or in this case, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` parameter), hence didnt match to use here.